# Countable objects and empty

Tags: php, count

If you do empty() on an array with no elements in it, you get true.  However, if you do empty() on a Countable object with a count of 0 then you get false.  It seems to me a 0 count Countable should be considered empty.  Am I missing something?

```
<?php

class Test implements Countable
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function count ()
    {
        return intval (abs ($this -> count));
    }
}

$test = new Test ();

var_dump (empty ($test));
var_dump (count ($test));

$test -> count = 10;

var_dump (empty ($test));
var_dump (count ($test));
```

I would have expected the first call to empty to return true, but it doesn't.

Is there a reasonable reason for this to be the case, or is it a bug?

Comment: The PHP manual explicitly defines *emptyness* and does not mention anything about `Countable`. I'd provide a link if I weren't on mobile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/empty):

```
Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

The following things are considered to be empty:

* "" (an empty string)
* 0 (0 as an integer)
* 0.0 (0 as a float)
* "0" (0 as a string)
* NULL
* FALSE
* array() (an empty array)
* var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

I think `$test` in your case is still considered an `Object`, which is not in the list of what empty would return as `TRUE`

Comment: OK, I guess it would be nice if the manual explicitly spelt out what to expect in this particular case

Comment: @GordonM I think it would be difficult for them to specify each corner cases like this, it's safest to just provide the list of what would return TRUE and correctly return FALSE for anything not in the list :)

Comment: Just a note stating that a Countable will not be considered empty even if its count is 0 would be nice though.

Answer (score 5):

As stated above, `empty()` does not consider `count($obj) == 0` to be "empty". The reason this doesn't doesn't work as expected is because arrays do not implement `Countable` i.e.

```
array() instanceof Countable // false
```

Probably an obvious workaround, but figured I would post this here.

```
function is_empty ($val) {
  return empty($val) || ($val instanceof Countable && empty(count($val)));
}
```

Example:

```
class Object implements Countable {

  protected $attributes = array();

  // ...

  public function count () {
    return count($this->attributes);
  }

}

$obj = new Object();
is_empty($obj) // TRUE
```

*I should note that this solution works in my case, because I would have already defined `is_empty()` for prettiness alongside the other `is_*` methods.*